# vscode-go: Any workaround to get `go vet` running with `-tags=windows` on linux?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

In my .vscode/settings.json file I have

```
"go.toolsEnvVars": {
    "GOFLAGS": "-tags=windows"
},
```

Which works in that Windows specific Declarations are seen by gopls now. But `go vet` Warnings are now not displayed anymore, likely due to [#64179](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/64179) - the underlying issue has already been reported at Apr 10, 2021 via [#45488](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45488).

Anyone knows of a workaround?

I searched on https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/settings.md for options that could be helpful, but haven't found something yet.

Comment: Found a solution: Use `"GOOS": "windows"` instead of just setting tags=windows

Answer (score 0):

Setting the GOOS instead of just the tags works as expected. In .vscode/settings.json this looks like:

```
"go.toolsEnvVars": {
    "GOOS": "windows"
},
```